# Android app to get .aspx form response

Tags: android, asp.net

I'm new to Android development.  I'm working on an app for use at work - I'm an EMT.  I was hoping to use the state's registry as a means of authenticating the user as an active provider.  https://ems.health.state.pa.us/emsreg/activepractitioners.aspx

I know nothing of asp, except that I should be able to pass some input through the URL with ?name=value.  But when I inspect the element of the last name field...

```
input name="_ctl0:_ctl0:SessionLinkBar:Content:tbxLName" type="text" 
id="_ctl0__ctl0_SessionLinkBar_Content_tbxLName"
```

I can't use this.  Honestly not even sure what I'm looking at here.  Is ":" a container?

Ultimately I'd like to take the user input on 2 edit texts (last name & certification #), click a button to `POST` them to the `activepractitioners.aspx`, and either get the whole response and pare down for what I need (Status Active, which I've yet to find labeled on the site) or verify the response then query its label.

I've tried a few of the methods here and I keep crashing the emulator.  Also I'd rather not see all the strikethroughs in Android Studio from deprecated methods.  I welcome all help, but please remember I'm a n00b - take it slow for me.  Thanks!

UPDATE:
I've gotten some results using JSoup.  I get to a landing page that should contain just one result (the certification # is unique) and a link.  The format of the link is as follows:
`<a id="_ctl0__ctl0_SessionLinkBar_Content_dgSearchResults__ctl2_lnk" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;_ctl0$_ctl0$SessionLinkBar$Content$dgSearchResults$_ctl2$lnk&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">`

It uses javascript to invoke "doPostBack."  Any idea on how to automate this too?  As it is I can parse the response to a document and scrape the table for the word "active."  But I'd like a bit of fool-proofing.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Android development, Can you able to tell us what is your crash report ?

Comment: I'd run and deleted too many iterations of this, and too tired to take note of the logs. I ran what was left in the project a moment ago - that last crash happened because it was still on the main thread.  So I'm starting over again with AsyncHttpClient.

Comment: Everything else i've tried gets app FC.  So no errors get thrown.  What I really need to know is what the actual key is to pass on to the form.  Or what can be used to search the page for "id=_superlongstringhere" so I can input to the element directly.  If anyone knows how to make it work in the URL, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to Android dev, I suggest you to spend some time having a look to Google Android [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) APIs.

It allows you to easily set up GET and POST requests (and works great).

Comment: For all my searching, I see no way of using Volley to sniff out an "id=" tag.  You know of a way?

Comment: @DavidRamirez sorry, I was suggesting you Volley just for the http requests. For the `id` topic: if you can't complete your goal by using `id`, try to use the `tag` attribute for the views: `view.setTag(x)` / `view.getTag()` / `view.findViewWithTag()`. From [Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html): Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that "Tag" was the key, not the value.  I shouldn't be working on this when I'm so tired.  Thank you for your response!

Comment: @DavidRamirez you're welcome ;) if my answer helped you, please upvote it, thanks!